# How do I embed a link to a YouTube video in PowerPoint without ads?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, youtube, advertisements

I embed youtube links in Powerpoint without a problem.  Google and bing have lots of information teaching the embedding.  However, when I present the pptx in a slide show to my audience, I do not want to see the ads.  You know, when watching youtube, sometimes in the middle an ad may pop up. The ad is a video lasting more than a minute.  You can click "Skip Ads" if you don't want to watch the ad.  I wonder if there is a way to prevent the ad interruption during a slide show of a pptx that embeds a youtube link.

Any advice or clue is much appreciated.

JD

Comment: Depending on how you feel about the Youtube ToS, maybe just downloading the video could be for you.

Comment: Use youtube-dl to download the youtube video https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youtube-dl

Comment: Particularly in a business environment you probably don't want to disregard youtube's TOS. Signing up for youtube premium and logging in before your presentation might be an option.

Comment: If the only way to avoid ads is to sign up for YouTube Premium that is what you have do. Otherwise you are asking the community to assist you in bypassing YouTube’s licensing and TOS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer : You can't for embedded video.
You're using YouTube's content and need to abide by their rules.
You'll find more information on YouTube Support
[Ads on embedded videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en).

The only workaround is to download the YouTube video using a downloader
and embed the downloaded video file.
You could use for example [youtube-dl](https://yt-dl.org/)
from the command-line or
[4K Video Downloader](https://www.4kdownload.com/welcome)
GUI on Windows.

You should be aware that the
[YouTube's Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms)
explicitly forbid it. You are not allowed to:

> access, reproduce, download, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, alter, modify or otherwise use any part of the Service or any Content except: (a) as expressly authorized by the Service; or (b) with prior written permission from YouTube and, if applicable, the respective rights holders;

However, YouTube has never sued anyone for downloading content. Several years ago, the company did consider suing one of the largest YouTube video downloaders (YouTube-MP3.org) for breach of the Terms of Service, but backed down after the site refused to budge.

---

Regarding whether a YouTube premium account will avoid ads:

From
[Ads on embedded videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en):

> Note that embedded videos will honor the same ad enablement settings as videos on youtube.com.

However, your Premium account is identified after logon on the
browser by tracking cookies stored into the browser's data,
and you will need these cookies for playing in PowerPoint
without ads.

I don't know if playing in PowerPoint uses cookies that are
found on the computer, meaning stored by logging into the browser.
To test if it does, I suggest before testing to log into the
YouTube Premium account on both Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer
(yes, really).

If the logged-into cookies don't work in PowerPoint, try the free
[LiveWeb extension](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm),
described as:

> Use LiveWeb to insert web pages into a PowerPoint slide and refresh the pages real-time during slide show. Display web pages without ever leaving the confines of your PowerPoint slide show. No coding required.

Note that YouTube Premium offers a 1-month free trial,
so you can do your tests and cancel it if none works.

Comment: This is a comment that should just read: “Short answer : You can't for embedded video.” The rest of this text is really irrelevant. Especially for a 100% off-topic post here.

Comment: I apologized that I didn't make my question clear.  I just changed the question title.  Yes, I don't want to violate youtube's TOS so that I only want to embed their links.  However, I also want to avoid the ads during my presentation in a power point slide show.  Does it help if I join and login to a premium account right before my presentation?

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: Hi harrymc, Thank you very much for the explanations.  I will try the one-month free account to see how it goes.  Also, Liveweb extension will be installed if needed.  I really appreciate the great help.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: This is perhaps the longest comment ever written.

Comment: Sure.  Thanks for the reminding.  I just marked it as accepted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MS has disabled the web browser control that LiveWeb relies on. It may still be possible to re-enable it via registry settings, but other than on one's own computer, that's a non-starter.

Comment: @harrymc “This is perhaps the longest comment ever written.” It is only excessively long because of you adding endless commentary on top of commentary. As I said in my first comment, this is a 100% off-topic post and your only post should have been a comment that simply read: “Short answer : You can’t for embedded video.” This is simply not an on-topic question here to begin with.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: That answer would not have helped the poster. Also, PowerPoint questions are on-topic.

Comment: @harrymc “Also, PowerPoint questions are on-topic.” The question core is not about PowerPoint but about how to link/embed YouTube content while skipping ads in the content. The question is effectively asking about the limits of the terms of service for YouTube. Initially the question was about breaking the terms of service by skipping ads and then asking if a premium account would help. None of this is on-topic for this site. Also, how is this tech advice “However, YouTube has never sued anyone for downloading content.” That is armchair legal advice; not tech advice.